# CSS loading locally but not in Heroku for a rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter-bootstrap

I'm following a rails prelaunch signup tutorial.  Bootstrap was working fine deployed on heroku, but then I modified the bootstrap_and_override file to include a logo.  When launching a rails server locally and viewing, the style is as I intended with bootstrap and the new header logo appearing.

Like I did before, I ran rake assets:precompile and pushed to git - followed this tutorial http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html which worked before showing the css while on heroku.  The html is showing but it looks like css and bootstrap are missing.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Would please select an answer that best worked for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 77):

Run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` on your local code

Commit the changes and deploy to heroku

Comment: This did the trick!  Looks like it was miss a few files in public/assets/

Comment: Worked for me as well! Thanks for posting this quick solution.

Answer (score 45):

Had the same exact problem, I don't know if it will help other in the future, but I got this on my "git push heroku master" push:

WARNINGS:

```
    Include "rails_12factor" gem to enable all platform features
```

Updated my gemfile,

```
    *group :production, :staging do
      gem 'pg'
      gem 'rails_12factor'
    end*
```

Ran it again, to my delight it installed these:

```
    Installing rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
           Installing rails_stdout_logging (0.0.1)
           Installing rails_12factor (0.0.2)
```

Site worked perfect after that.  Hope that helps someone, I'm new to all this.

Comment: See heroku docs about [rails_12factor](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-integration-gems)

Answer (score 22):

Check that in /config/environments/production.rb you have these set to true

`config.cache_classes = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true`

git add, git commit and push to heroku.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to rails, and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

If your using sass...before you go through all this other trouble...make sure your not mixing .css and .scss files in your assets folder.
Heroku seems to have some trouble mixing the two when compiling assets.  I can't explain why of if its an accurate explanation...but, in my own experience all I had to do to fix this was simply rename any .css files to .scss.

Comment: I had the issue that .css where not working but i set `config.assets.compile = true` and it worked. By default with rails 5 it was setted to `false`.

Comment: I had an issue using padrino where `normalize.min.css` wasn't showing up on heroku. I was linking to it in the html. I ended up renaming to `normalize.min.scss` and importing it in my `application.scss` file and it magically worked!

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out after trying about everything stackoverflow could suggest.  I simply checked git status, saw I had a bunch of uncommitted files (thought this would have been picked up by git push heroku master), then added, committed and pushed to git.  Then I started over, ran bundle install, precompiled assets and deployed to heroku and it is working.

Comment: I feel like an idiot, but thanks for the help. solved everything

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem in rails4 fixed with adding
a. `gem 'rails_12factor'`
b. `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Answer (score 1):

To load assets in production environment:

[How to load assets in production rails](https://taimoorchangaizpucitian.wordpress.com/2015/11/08/rails-production-environment-assets-loading/)

Note:
After following above link

```
rm -rf tmp/*
rm -rf public/assets/*
RAILS_ENV='production' rake assets:precompile
```

then restart your server

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot, but if you're using Chrome try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to reload the page as Chrome can sometimes cache old CSS settings.

Comment: this indirectly helped me out - I tested localhost:3000 on a different browser than chrome (my main development browser) and it turns out it wasn't working in development either and was just being cached by Chrome. (however ctrl+shift+R made no changes for me...)

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also happen when you are cloning an app and using a CDN for your assets.

Comment out `config.action_controller.asset_host` in `production.rb` if your heroku app is a staging site.

Answer (score -3):

I had to run `heroku run rake css:rebuild`