# Bootstrap Navigation Not Functioning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

Navbar is showing properly on localhost:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/9xqno903g60f3f0/2015-03-22%20at%207.01%20PM.png?dl=0

but when I push it to heroku I get something that doesn't have the same navbar:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/jjupo0xfxkyvm2f/2015-03-22%20at%207.01%20PM%20%281%29.png?dl=0

Not sure what's going on or if there is some extra command i need to enter for heroku to reflect the proper navbar changes.

logs are saying:

```
2015-03-23T01:51:38.865239+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/glyphicons-halflings-5737efb39ea936f62b6811688c4bb9f6.png")
```

and the header code looks like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Pinteresting</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Comment: I actually solved it by precompiling the assets, found in a recommendations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719541/css-loading-locally-but-not-in-heroku-for-a-rails-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` and deploy commited changes to heroku.