# css working in local but fails after deploying to heroku flask

Tags: python, css, heroku

I'm running a flask app and deploying to heroku. I changed a single line of code in a vendor distribution css by applying the style in the needed template page, but this does not work when deployed to heroku, while it works fine in local. I read on [precompiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719541/css-loading-locally-but-not-in-heroku-for-a-rails-app) but I couldn't find one for flask.

I am using this [scroller](https://amazingcarousel.com/). There's an item in it that centers all the elements, namely this:

```
#amazingcarousel-1 .amazingcarousel-item-container {
        padding: 6px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Testing further it seems like only changing the CSS from my static folder will change the text-align locally, and it seemed to have worked previously in local because I didn't clear the cache. Is there a way I can deploy my static css onto heroku?

Comment: show us your code.

Comment: updated with details @georgexsh

Answer (score 0):

I added the following and deployed successfully with my changes.

```
<div style="text-align:initial;">
    <!--thing I don't want aligned-->
</div>
```