# Rails app doesn't have css for styled components after uploading it on heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku, styled-components

I have a rails with react app. The  app works perfectly locally but when i upload it to heroku, all of the css disappears. I checked css for both(the  locally running app and the  one running on heroku) inside the developer tools tab. The one running locally  has css and the one on heroku doesnt  have  it.

I used styled  components to handle  the css for  my components, which is an unorthodox method and  probably why I am facing this  issue. Here's  is  how  how I added css(Example component:)

```
import React from 'react'

import Thumbnail from './Thumbnail'
import styled from 'styled-components';

 const Button = styled.a`
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor:pointer;
 border-radius: 0;
 background:  #fff;
 color: #a1271a !important
 padding: 10px 20px;
 font-size: 18px;

box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #473228,
-6px 6px #ef5f17,
-6px 6px 0px 3px #473228;`




const Item = (props) => {
   return (
      <div className="row pt-3 pb-3">
          <div className="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
            <div >
                <div className="card px-5">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-4">
                            <Thumbnail/> 
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-8">
                            <div className="pt-4 pb-4">
                                <h4>{props.title}</h4>
                                <p>{props.description}</p>
                                <div className="cta-wrapper">
                                     <Button onClick={props.handleVideoChange} className="btn cta-btn">Watch This Video</Button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

  export default Item
```

Things  I  have  tried so far:

1-add the  gem 'rails_12factor' to production group

2-set  'config.assets.compile = true' inside  #config/enviroments/production.rb

3- ran "heroku run yarn install" & "heroku run bundle  install"

4- ran "heroku buildpacks:add heroku/ruby --index 2" & " heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs --index 1"

none  of  these  have  worked  out so far.I feel its  just a configuration problem with heroku because  the app definitely works locally.I tried  to look for guides  for configuring  heroku but  have't  found  some thing  helpful so far. Any kind  of  help be  gratefully appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `RAILS_ENV='production' rake assets:precompile` on Heroku? I'm assuming you'll have to flip your #2 above. Don't forget to restart the server.

Comment: There are some others to try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719541/css-loading-locally-but-not-in-heroku-for-a-rails-app?rq=1

Comment: What are you using to compile your assets, webpacker or sprockets?

Comment: @beartech yes I have tried that aswell and it doesn't  work. Plus  i'm using  webpack to compile  my assets.